# How to get the correct 'base hook' to override a template file in a custom module?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

How can I find the 'base hook' to override a template file using a custom module?

'node' and 'user' are pretty straightforward, but others can be a little more elusive.

Example code...

MYMODULE.module:

```
/**
 ** Implements hook_theme().
 **/
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'username' => [
      'template' => 'username',
      'base hook' => 'how do you get this?',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: You don't need `template` if the template is named the same as the theme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look into the *.module file where the base hook is defined, in this case the User module. The base hook is the key of the template definition:

*user.module:*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */

function user_theme() {
  return [
    ... 
    'username' => [
      'variables' => ['account' => NULL, 'attributes' => [], 'link_options' => []],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then in your *.module file

*mymodule.module*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return [
    'username__mymodule_template' => [
      'base hook' => 'username',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Start the name of your own hook  with the base hook and double underscores.

Comment: Want to cross-reference this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200602/override-theme-template-from-module-without-implementing-a-theme. Note, for the above template file to apply you will need to alter/add a theme suggestion so this file is looked for. Example `hook_theme_suggestions_username_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables)`