# How can I load a template from a custom module on a certain page?

Tags: theming, 9

I have a page at path `/user/{id}/module`, and I'm trying to have Drupal load a custom template from my module when this page is accessed.

The twig debug output shows suggestions for the template name like below, but it doesn't seem to pick the template up even after cache rebuilds. The page needs to show for all users so cannot pin it to a specific id, but `html--user--module.html.twig` is not respected.

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * html--user--module.html.twig
   * html--user--123456.html.twig
   * html--user--%.html.twig
   * html--user.html.twig
   x html.html.twig
-->
```

Is there some syntax I've not been able to find like `html--user--wildcard-id--module.html.twig`?

Comment: You have to do special stuff for Drupal to look in your module's directory for a template override.  By default it only looks to the active theme.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override theme template from module without implementing a theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200602/override-theme-template-from-module-without-implementing-a-theme)

Comment: @leymannx thanks for that. It's the same solution but different way to encounter the issue, I have both a custom theme and module. I voted for Sam's answer on this question but don't have the rep to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2):

**Use template from a module**

You have to specify the template in `hook_theme()` with the correct base hook.

Here is example for hook 'node':

```
function MY_MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'node__custom-type__full' => [
      'template' => 'node--custom-type--full',
      'base hook' => 'node',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE') . '/templates/content', // if custom
    ],
  ];
}
```

**Other solution : create new suggestion**

You can do this in `theme_suggestions_alter()`

Check [theme_suggestion_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x)

Here is a example, this is a solution **to create template suggestion for form with id form** :

```
function MY_THEME_theme_suggestions_alter($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  if ($hook === 'form' && !empty($variables['element']['#id'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'form__' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['element']['#id']);
  }
}
```

(Create for me the form--**user-login-form**.html.twig)

In you case, replace `$hook` by `html` and add id user